# Javascript nested loops not showing full matrix

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to print a list of coordinates, and I thought a nested loop would be the appropriate way to do it, so I wrote the following code (very simple):

```
var x = 23;
var y = 34;
var z = 28;

var div = document.getElementById("coordinates");

div.innerHTML += "<ul>";

for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
        for (var k = 1; k <= z; k++) {
            div.innerHTML += "<li>X: " + i + " Y: " + j + " Z: " + k + "</li>";
        }
    }
}

div.innerHTML += "</ul>";
```

When I do that I expect a really huge amount of elements (in this case 23*34*28 elments) but instead I get this:

```
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 1
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 2
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 3
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 4
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 5
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 6
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 7
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 8
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 9
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 10
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 11
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 12
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 13
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 14
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 15
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 16
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 17
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 18
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 19
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 20
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 21
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 22
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 23
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 24
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 25
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 26
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 27
X: 1 Y: 1 Z: 28
```

When I expected it to continue with something like:

```
X: 1 Y: 2 Z: 1
X: 1 Y: 2 Z: 2
X: 1 Y: 2 Z: 3
X: 1 Y: 2 Z: 4
...
```

It's like it only looped once through the two first loops.

I think I'm trying to do something really simple, so what am I doing wrong?

PD: For now I don't need to save memory or any kind of optimization, I know loops like this can be huge if the x,y,z values are high.

Comment: Of course it's working.

Comment: Works for me. What is the problem?

Comment: this simplified version being OK, if this behaviour happens in your code, you probably have another code somewhere that interfer with `i`, `j`, `x` or `y` variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For now I don't need to save memory or any kind of optimization, I know loops like this can be huge if the x,y,z values are high.

You do need to, because you're asking the browser to do a **huge** amount of unnecessary work, and probably hitting a limit; the code is fine otherwise.

**`x.innerHTML += ...` is an antipattern.** Every time you read from `innerHTML`, the browser has to run through the full tree of the element you use it on and build a string in memory with the HTML representation of that DOM tree; everytime you assign to it, the browser has to tear down the old tree, parse the new HTML, and build new DOM elements to replace the old tree. `+=` is reading, adding more, and then assigning.

As I write this (having already written the snippet below), the jsFiddle I dropped your original code into is *still running* and has been running since before I started this answer. :-) (Edit: It finally stopped, and did show the full list.)

Instead, create your new node and append it. In your case, you can even add all the `li`s to the `ul` before adding it to the document, then add it to the document with a single operation. If I do that, it works, and fairly quickly:

```js
var x = 23;
var y = 34;
var z = 28;

var div = document.getElementById("coordinates");

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
        for (var k = 1; k <= z; k++) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
              "X: " + i + " Y: " + j + " Z: " + k
            )
          );
          ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}

div.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="coordinates"></div>
```